# How to plot a CSV file and a mathematical function on the same ggplot2 plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to accomplish a very basic task using R+ggplot2: plotting data from a CSV file along with a polynomial fit obtained outside R. The way I am trying to do it is the following:

```
library(ggplot2)

# This CSV file contains dates and numeric values
data <- read.csv("data.csv")

# I want to plot using numeric values in the x axis, so I am adding this column
data$idx <- as.numeric(row.names(data))

# Some arbitrary function to plot over the data
eq = function(x){x*x}

# Plotting the data
p <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=idx, y=Close), data=data)

# Adding the function
p + stat_function(fun=eq)

print(p)
```

The problem is that this is only plotting the data. I can't get the function to appear in the same plot no matter what I do. The function is supposed to be calculated at the idx values created above, by the way.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you define `aes()` within `ggplot()` call and not within `geom_line`? I suspect those mappings are not available to `stat_function` if defined only within `geom_line`.

Comment: Then I get a plot of the function, but this time without the plot of the data points. The original plot just disappears and gets replaced.

Comment: Can you provide a dummy example that demonstrates this?